# Is it safe to upload a project with Firebase Database on Github?

Tags: github, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm currently working on an app with a Firebase Database for it's backend.

I want to upload it to the Github to show on my LinkedIn what I'm currently working on. Is it safe to upload through Github without anyone else accessing my Firebase database or any other security issues?

Comment: Is the database information stored within the project? Or is there just a linked relationship?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So long as you've written thorough [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) for your database, this should be totally safe! The whole idea of the Firebase Realtime Database is to be able to provide direct access from untrusted clients.

If you aren't confident in your security rules, I'd encourage you to look into making them robust. Just because you aren't sharing your source code doesn't mean someone isn't looking for vulnerabilities.